# Visual studio and visual code and sublime can't display russian texts?

Tags: notepad++, visual-studio, text-editors, visual-studio-code, sublime-text-3

I have some source files which have russian comments in them

the problem is that the comments seems to be gibberish instead of proper russian, seems like text editors cant properly display it?

for example i have this :

ïîääåðæèâàåò

But the weird thing is that this "ïîääåðæèâàåò" seems to be quite common on the web, if you search in google for example

how can i recover the russian texts from these gibberish texts?

But notepad++ displays them properly!

Comment: consider a)what font you are using b)what encoding the file is set to (should be utf-...  and not ascii),  c)ensure the font is installed in windows

Comment: I just tried typing hebrew in visual studio code and it showed fine..  It says utf-8 on the bottom, (utf-8 supports lots of characters, as it's a unicode based encoding),  and looking at the font(file..preferences....),  those seem to support unicode characters, and hebrew language is installed for me. So all those factors help no doubt.

Comment: also there are different types of unicoe encodings.. utf-8,  utf-16   ,  there's with BOM and without BOM.. There's UTF-16 BE and UTF-16 LE..  You could check which it is.. The fine command might help.

Comment: If you share the file here somehow e.g. with a google drive link then we could check what type of file it is.. with some tips how to identify the type of file..  Show the first bunch of characters of `xxd -p blah.txt`  (you can get xxd from VIM7)